# Google Drive API issue searching including shared files

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm performing some file list searches in Google Drive API and have found out that there is a mismatch between the searches in the API and the one performed directly in the Google Drive Webpage on Shared files. Due to character issue.

If I search for "företagsrevision" in shared files like with "fullText contains 'företagsrevision'" it will not find anything. But if I search the same in Google Drive Web I get hits.

If I use some other text that does not have åäö there is not issue, but what should i convert this characters to?

Answer (score 0):

The characters should be url escaped (as they appear in a url). Other than that, they should be found correctly. If not, it might be a bug. To help, what encoding are you using for the characters?